# Configure RabbitMQ with SSL

Tags: python, ssl, rabbitmq

I am trying to configure a basic SSL authentification with RabbitMQ using [this RabbitMQ container](https://github.com/Nepitwin/RabbitSSL).

After following all the steps mentioned, I fail to run the either the consumer or the producer from the Python examples. The error that appears is the following one:

```
Connection to 127.0.0.1:5671 failed: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645) ConnectionClosed
```

The certificates `cacert.pem`, `cert.pem` and `key.pem` I have asumed that are the `cacert` from the directory `testca`, and the `cert.pem` and `key.pem` should be the ones that can be found in the client and server directories (depending on whether the consumer or the produces is executed).

Therefore, my question is if these asumptions are right or not and finally, how could the aforementioned example should be executed in order to not obtain the SSL error that appears either after the execution of the consumer or the producer.